# Is there a syntax error in my media query?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to run this media query, and I suspect there may be a syntax error.

I've tried specifying that my media query is for a screen, and it didn't work.

This project is on codepen, if you want to see the full code.

https://codepen.io/Codemeena/pen/BEydjE?editors=0100

One of the requirements to complete the project is to have a media query.

```
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: green;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  right: 0px;
  @media (max-width: 600px) {
    flex-direction: column;
   }
}
```

I expect the flex-direction element to be purple, like the other css elements.

Comment: Which tool are you using to check for that "same color"? Have you tried hovering over the colored section - often, some types of tool tips are used to give more information about such irregularities

Comment: Are you using SASS? If not, that won't work.

Comment: Your media query should be **outside** the `ul` tag

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The syntax you are using is supported in SASS, but not in CSS.

Media queries have to live *outside* of rulesets, not inside them.

```
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: green;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  right: 0px;
}

@media (max-width: 600px) {
  ul {
    flex-direction: column;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using regular CSS, the media query should be outside of the element. Then the media query should wrap the element you are trying to affect.

```
ul {
      list-style-type: none;
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
      overflow: hidden;
      background-color: green;
      position: fixed;
      top: 0;
      right: 0px;
    }

@media (max-width: 600px) {
   ul {
            flex-direction: column;
    }
}
```